# not able to run selenium using batch file. getting warning as Can't link and determine methods of class and error as Unable to read methods on class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
D:\Myprogram\ProjectName>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class Project.ProjectName
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class Project.ProjectName - unable to resolve class reference javax/mail/MessagingException
[TestNG] Running:
  D:\Myprogram\ProjectName\testng.xml


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Comment: solved!! actually i didnt put selenium-server-standalone.zar in my lib folder

Comment: but test is not passing getting failure but when i am running through eclipse test is passed